# Strange gdate results

Tags: bash, date

I have the following simple commands

```
me@mymachine~$ some_date="2019-09-20 22:02:19"
me@mymachine~$ gdate -d "${some_date} + 24 hours" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2019-09-19 19:02:19
```

My initial date is on 9/20 and when I'm adding 24 hours to it I'm getting a date before that.  I'm guessing this has something to do w/ timezones or something but why wouldn't it just keep the same one (or assume UTC or something)

This is currently running `bash` in a Mac

**EDIT**

Looks like changing the command to

```
gdate -d "${some_date} - 24 hours" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

gives the expected result but this syntax seems strange to me

**EDIT 2**
Another date that is giving weird results

```
me@mymachine~$ some_date="2019-09-19 01:48:02"
me@mymachine~$ gdate -d "${some_date} - 24 hours"
Thu Sep 19 22:48:02 EDT 2019
```

This example is directionally correct however it doesn't appear to be adding a full 24 hours?  Am I not understanding the gdate syntax correctly?

Comment: I get the same result whether I add or subtract 24 hours.

Comment: It appears that the `-d` argument is being parsed in UTC unless it contains an explicit timezone. But the output is in the local timezone.

Comment: Looks like this is correct, if you write up the answer you'll get the check

Comment: I can't find any corroboration of this in the documentation, it actually says that it uses the system default timezone to parse dates.

Comment: I've noticed `date -d "${some_date} 24 hours ago"` produces `Wed Sep 18 01:48:02 EDT 2019`. Same for '1 days ago'